# My Discord bot is messaging continuously even though I programmed it to do it once

Tags: node.js, discord, bots

I was creating a discord bot and was testing it. When I say Hi or Yo it will msg me an emoji.
It is working fine but, the problem is that it is msg the emoji continuously.

Here is my code:

```
console.log('Beep Beep! ');

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();  // Client is the object that connects with the discord API itself to run the bot
client.login('API');
client.on('ready', readyDiscord);

function readyDiscord(){
    console.log('');
}

client.on('message', gotMessage);

function gotMessage(msg){
    if (msg.channel.id == '849147593392914453' && msg.content === 'Hi' || 'Yo'){
         // msg.reply('');
         msg.channel.send('');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to follow mine since it seems the answer is already here, but here is what I would do.

Also, don't show your token to anyone. The token is your key to your bot, so I'd recommend resetting your bot's token in the Discord Developer Portal.

Anyways, here is what I would do:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.login('TOKEN_HERE');
client.once('ready', () => {
      console.log('I am ready to help others! ');
});

const channelID = '849147593392914453';

client.on('message', message => {
if (message.channel.id == channelID && message.content.toLowerCase() === 'hi' || 'yo' || 'hey'){
         message.reply('Hey! ');
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about the token

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you added the [API token](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=token) to this post. API token should be kept private at all times.

Second of all, you can use [a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) if you're trying to send your message only once. I tested the attached snippet locally and it works fine. The message will be sent only once.

```js
function gotMessage(msg){
    let isReplied = false;

    function reply() {
    if (!isReplied && (msg.content === 'Hi' || 'Yo')){
         console.log('');
         isReplied = true
        }
    }
    return reply
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about the token